# Efficient way to calculate fade values between RGB colors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, colors

I'm tinkering with my keyboard lighting using a node wrapper. The included fade function uses a huge array with values from `[0,0,0]` to `[255,255,255]` then finds the start and end points and just iterates the array. That means that when fading from blue `[0,0,255]` to black `[0,0,0`] it actually passes through other colors instead of just counting down the blue value down from `255` to `0`. So all fades between colors are just a mess and look horrible.

So I created my own fade function like this:

```
function ledSet(led, r, g, b, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function() { cue.set(led, r, g, b); }, timeout);
}

function difference(array1, array2) {
    var max = 0;

    for(var i in array1) {
        for(var j in array2) {
            var value = Math.abs(array1[i]-array2[j]);
            if(value > max) {
                max = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

function fadeLed(key, from, to, duration) {

    var steps = difference(from, to);
    var interval = duration/steps;

    for(var i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {
        var rgb = [];

        for(var j in from) {

            var change = Math.abs(from[j]-to[j])/steps*i;
            var value = Math.ceil((from[j] > to[j]) ? from[j]-change : from[j]+change);

            rgb.push(value);
        }
        ledSet(key, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], interval*i);
    }

}

fadeLed('Enter', [0,0,255], [0,0,0], 500);
```

It works great on a single or few LED's, but is insanely slow for multiple LEDs (like changing colors for the entire keyboard). I'll try optimizing using an option to set multiple LEDs with one command (if multiple LEDs share the same start and end color), but I'm wondering if there is a more mathematically efficient way to calculate the needed values for fading between two RGB colors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scheduling a lot of timeouts that way.

What you can do alternatively is to only schedule one timeout function and schedule another one from within that function.

To make a simple example - instead of something like this:

```
function f(i) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i * 100);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  f(i);
}
```

you can do something like this:

```
function f(i, m) {
  if (i < m) {
    console.log(i);
    setTimeout(() => f(i + 1, m), 100);
  }
}

f(0, 10);
```

Some other things that you can do:

- precompute the values before you start
- optimize the steps to not make too much of them
- have one function in fixed intervals that runs multiple other functions
- use a polyfill of requestAnimationFrame to make some consistent intervals

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I'll try to figure out how to make it work with your example.